# Having trouble successfully unit testing my Python program: No such file or directory....0 of 1 tests passed

Tags: python, unit-testing, compilation

I forked a repository from Github that contains a data engineering project. From the repository, I have created a Python script that works as it's supposed to on my local machine.

Basically, the program is supposed to read in an input .txt file, perform some clean-up and calculations on the file, and return an output .txt file.

The repository also has the code written to test the program. However, I'm still in the process of learning how to correctly compile and execute my code, and I'm running into problems with the unit testing.

From the command line, I run the file './test_run.sh' and the test shows that my program is correctly reading in my input file AND it is successfully creating a test directory for my output, including an "output" directory.

The problem is that the program is supposed to create an output file 'data_output.txt" inside the output directory, but this is not happening.

Here is the error message I'm getting:

```
$ ./test_run.sh
diff: ./test_output/output/data_output.txt: No such file or directory
[FAIL]: test_1
diff: ./test_output/output/data_output.txt: No such file or directory
[Thu Feb 15 20:56:11 EST 2018] 0 of 1 tests passed
```

What would I need to change so that my program creates the data_output.txt file and writes my program output to this file?

Comment: A few questions.  Does the user you're running the program as have access to write to that directory? When you run the program, does the data_output.txt file exist, but is empty, or does it not exist at all?  What happens if you create the file, and then run it again?

Comment: I don't know if the user I'm running the program as has access to write to that directory. How would I know that? As for the 'data_output.txt file,'  the test process creates a brand new '/test_output' directory that did not exist before, and that also creates the '/output' directory inside of that and the 'data_output.tx' file inside of that. If you create this directory beforehand, the test overwrites any previously created files and then gives me the same error.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Linux Mint 18.3

Comment: @trueCamelType Linux Mint 18.3

Comment: If it's creating that file in the directory that it's needed in, then it has permission to write there, so that's probably not the problem.  In order to troubleshoot much more I'd need to see the code that's running.  There may be someone else with more experience that can make a better educated guess than I could.